# REST Api error "Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have tried below api to upload file to library folder.

```
 var url = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/testDocumentList/testFolder')/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
            _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);
```

I get error `Server relative urls must start with SPWeb.ServerRelativeUrl`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try removing the / character from the beggining of the parameter of GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl function. Change it to: `'testDocumentList/testFolder'`.

Your updated code should look like this:

```
var url = String.format(
            "{0}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('testDocumentList/testFolder')/Files/Add(url='{1}', overwrite=true)",
            _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl, fileName);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was having this error in SharePoint Online. My site collection URL contains "/sites". So to fix this issue I have to pass URL as follow:

```
var requesturi= "";
    if((_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl) && (_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl.indexOf("sites")>0))
    {
        requesturi = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('"+_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+"/Shared%20Documents/document.docx')/$value";
    }
    else
    {
        requesturi = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared%20Documents/document.docx')/$value";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[[image: please try with angularJs]

Please try with angularJs & =>  `fileUrl = 'subsite01/Pages/file-0001.aspx'`